# error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 4

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, gcc

I am new to python and don't know much about linux commands. So please, consider my problem. I have tried to run the command:

```
    python pyglpk_setup.py build
```

but I got following results:

```
    running build  
    running build_ext  
    building 'glpk' extension  
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -Isrc -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/glpk.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/glpk.o -m64  
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: src/glpk.c: No such file or directory  
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files  
    compilation terminated.  
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 4
```

I think I have installed dependencies and tried other stuffs to make it run  but I am not able to resolve it.

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Welcome to the site. could you please use block code for you command and error result.

Answer (score 0):

---

Seems you have a corrupt glpk :

> error: src/glpk.c: No such file or directory

Please get a new "glpk-0.3.tar.gz" https://pypi.python.org/packages/dc/6c/33e383f6613a90865bddeb1666c2b6121563b21a41d12d75bc2836a6bfdb/glpk-0.3.tar.gz

```
$ tar xvf glpk-0.3.tar.gz
$ cd glpk-0.3/
$ python setup.py build
```

→ → No errors here.

---